# Firebase realtime-database console not exporting JSON

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am trying to export JSON data from my realtime-database on the firebase console, however for large nodes it is not working.

[image]

and

[image]

Previously, the firebase console exported JSON to nodes in offline mode, but now it does not seem to work anymore.

Does anyone know if there was any limitation or is there a problem?

Comment: I just quickly tested and the "Export JSON" still works the same for me. Please give it a shot in an incognito window with all browser plugins disabled. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I just tested it with another clean browser and it still does not work. I'll get in touch with Firebase support. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this response from Firebase Support:

> Hi there,
>
> I'm Kevin from Firebase Support, and I'll be handling this ticket.
>
> Are you in "read-only" mode when you experienced the issue with the
>   Realtime Database export? If so, there is already an internal bug
>   filed for this. Our engineering team is already aware of this.
>   However, I can't share any details for now, so I'll have this ticket
>   open to keep you posted with any updates.
>
> For now, you may try to copy the URL indicated on the error page and
>   paste that on the browser's address bar to manually download the
>   exported data. You can also navigate to a deeper part of your database
>   and export smaller chunks.
>
> Since you are on Blaze plan, you may also enable the Automated Backups
>   and download the compressed files containing the exported data.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.
>
> Thanks, Kevin

I copied the link to the browser and managed to download the data perfectly.